# Can we prevent or detect Console popup event?

Tags: javascript, service-console

We're using the [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm) to display a custom status bar in the console. This works really well, except that the users can click on the status bar component (indicated by the hand cursor at the bottom of image below) to open up a popup window. Ideally, we don't want/need the user to open this (there's nothing to show, and in fact currently reads "This Space Intentionally Left Blank"). I've looked all over the documentation, but I can't seem to cause the status bar to not pop out a window at all, so our current implementation is to just call         `sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentVisible(false);` using `window.setInterval`, but if we set the value too small, it lags the console, and if we set it too large, the window pops up and the user can see it until the next time it gets closed. Ideally, we'd like nothing to happen at all when the user clicks the status bar. Is there a way we prevent the custom console component from popping out its default popup window?

[image: Console Popup for No Particular Reason]

Here's the Visualforce page that implements the console component:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/34.0/integration.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ctiStatusJS)}" />
    <h1>
        This Space Intentionally Left Blank
    </h1>
</apex:page>
```

For the purposes of this component, here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
!function(window, document, undefined) {
    function heartbeat() {
        sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentVisible(false);
    }
    function init() {
        window.setInterval(heartbeat, 250);
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
}(window, document)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this `onCustomConsoleComponentButtonClicked()` to track the click event and `setCustomConsoleComponentWindowVisible(false)` to close the window.

Along with that, make window height and width to 1 pixel. (Though we cant make it 0).

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/34.0/integration.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var eventHandler = function (result) {                 
            closeWindow(result);
        };

        var closeWindow = function closeWindow(result) {
            sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentVisible(false, result);
        };

        sforce.console.onCustomConsoleComponentButtonClicked(eventHandler);
    </script>
    <h1>
        This Space Intentionally Left Blank
    </h1>
</apex:page>
```

For more information, Refer [onCustomConsoleComponentButtonClicked()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_oncustomconsolecomponentbuttonclicked.htm) and [setCustomConsoleComponentVisible()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_setcustomconsolecomponentvisible.htm#topic-title)

I have tried that, window is closing on clicking footer component.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: It happens, glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

I would think you should be able to listen to that event using a click listener. The toolkit has an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_addeventlistener.htm) method, so something like:

```
sforce.console.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // check if the proper component was clicked
});
```

You can also specify `tabId` in an optional third parameter (`additionalParams`), if you want to limit the scope of this listener.

I can't reproduce your layout to determine any further steps, but it ought to fire.